# How do I get Tortoise to not see .java in bin?

Tags: java, tortoisesvn

Somehow, Tortoise against Subversion can't seem to figure out that the source is not in the bin directory:

1) When we set up a commit, all of the source shows up as missing from the bin directory:

```
Path                     Extension  Text Status
bin/com/.../File1.java   .java      missing
bin/com/.../File2.java   .java      missing
```

2) An update will sometimes do the following:

```
Action    Path
Command   Update
Restored  C:\dev\...\bin\...\File1.java
Restored  C:\dev\...\bin\...\File2.java
```

A few notes about this:

-Nothing shows in bin/ in the Repo Browser.
-Yes, there is an svn:ignore for bin.
-In example 1 above, the .java files show up in bin/ with green checkmarks.
-In example 2 above, there are no .java files in bin/
-If you try to delete the bin files from bin/, it will delete them from src/ instead (this has happened to 2 developers trying to clear up this issue).

Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!

Comment: You're saying when you use svn delete to remove the files from the bin folder, it deletes them from src, or when you delete them via Windows explorer (not Tortoise or svn command line) it deletes them from src?

Comment: Is there an svn:externals property on any of the folders involved?

Comment: When you delete the files from the bin folder, it deletes them from source in the repository, yes.

I don't believe there are any externals on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `bin` folder and see what the `.svn` contents look like, or right-click on the `bin` folder and select `Repo-browser` and see what path it shows you.

**It sounds as if you(or your build scripts) may have copied the `src/.svn` directory over to your `bin` directory.**

If that is the case, then Tortoise will "see" your `bin` as your `src` and think that you are missing source files from the checkout of `src`.

Comment: This solved part of my problem.  I was able to address the copying problem by adding the following string to both the Java Build Path/Source properties:  **/.svn/*

I also had to add the “svn:ignore *” Subversion property to the bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted all the .svn folders in the bin folder. Ran a clean-up and added the bin to ignored folders. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem. I checked, and yes, `bin/.svn/entries` was pointing to the `src` folder on our svn server. I got it to stop complaining about the bin folder being out of sync by simply renaming `bin/.svn` to `bin/dotsvn` (so as not to do anything permanent). Now all my projects are correctly showing as their status.